Movie about a man who returns to his hometown and remembers childhood friend
My girlfriend mentioned a movie in a discussion we had on the theme. However, she doesn't remember the title or any of the actors, and the film seemed interesting, so I am asking it here.
What we know:

main character returns to the town (or village, she is not sure) where he was born
he remembers about a paralyzed girl (probably as a result of polio), who was his friend in childhood (I am using word "childhood" loosely, my girlfriend doesn't know their exact age, but they were young)
he sees an adult woman (his age) that bears resemblance to the girl he was friend with
however, the paralyzed girl either died in accident or killed herself while she was still a child

What I think:

the film was made in the last 15 years (my girl rarely watches older films)
it was possibly a TV film (there are a lot of US/German/French TV film shown in my country)
the film was in English language (she would probably remember if it wasn't)


Sounds like Till Human Voices Wake Us with Guy Pearce and Helena Bonham Carter from 2002.

Psychoanalyst Dr. Samuel Franks heads back to his rural hometown of Genoa, Victoria, Australia to bury his recently deceased father, Dr. David Franks. Once back and staying at the now empty family home, Sam reminisces about one fateful summer of his teen-aged life when he was back from boarding school, and spent much of his time with the Lewis family, most specifically with leg brace wearing Silvy Lewis, the two who had a deep emotional connection with each other. His reminiscences are sparked in part by meeting in Genoa a young amnesiac calling herself Ruby. Some of the situations Sam finds himself in with Ruby are reminiscent of those he spent with Silvy that summer. Despite what happened that summer, Sam begins to wonder if Ruby and Silvy are indeed the same person, or... 

See if the trailer rings any bells (it starts around 0:25):




If it wouldn't be for the Polio aspect, I would think it could be an adaptation of Stephen King's, Hearts in Atlantis...

Hearts in Atlantis is a 2001 American-Australian mystery drama
  thriller film directed by Scott Hicks and starring Anthony Hopkins and
  Anton Yelchin. It is loosely adapted from Stephen King's Dark Tower
  tie-in Low Men in Yellow Coats, a novella in the collection Hearts in
  Atlantis after which the film was named.
Hearts in Atlantis tells the story of Robert "Bobby" Garfield, a
  middle-aged man recollecting his past, in particular the summer when
  he was eleven years old. During that summer, he and his two friends,
  Carol Gerber and John "Sully" Sullivan, experienced many things
  together, the most mysterious of which was meeting an older gentleman
  named Ted Brautigan...
Bobby, Carol and John have frequent conflicts with the local town
  bully, Harry Doolin, whom Ted is able to scare away by looking into
  his mind and finding out that his violence is used to cover up the
  fact that he is secretly a cross-dresser. However, at one point, Harry
  hurts Carol, and when Ted manipulates her dislocated shoulder into
  place, Liz arrives, after being raped by her boss, and mistakenly
  believes that Ted is a child molester. She is confronted by Ted's
  ability to tell her the truth about what she has been through, and how
  her behavior is affecting her relationship with her son, providing
  another reason that Ted must leave. That and the "low men" are closing
  in on him. Ted is eventually captured with the help of a tip from Liz.
  As some form of closure, Ted yells to Bobby as he is being driven away
  that he wouldn't have missed a moment "not for all the world", and
  later Bobby mirrors the same feelings. Bobby is later confronted by
  Harry but Bobby grabs the latter's baseball bat and beats him with it.
  Liz later finds a new job in Boston and moves the family there.
  Before he leaves, Bobby and Carol say their goodbyes and share a final kiss.
At the end of the film, a grown up Bobby (who has travelled back to attend Sully's funeral) meets a young girl named Molly, who turns out
  to be Carol's daughter. Bobby produces a picture of a young Carol (who
  died in recent years) and gives it to Molly to keep.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearts_in_Atlantis_(film)
Trailer:




It is not the film I was looking for, but thank You for the answer. It is funny that I have read Hearts in Atlantis several years ago and hadn't thought of ti now, because it is close enough to be considered for an answer.

I hope you find what you're looking for! :)

I did, it was the answer above Yours :)

I see that now! Sorry about that! :D
